# How to depency inject a custom class with a constructor into the service container using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have some understanding problem with the Laraver service container.

This is my custom class:
**MyCustomClass.php**

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public string $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public static function make(string $name)
    {
        return app(static::class, ['name' => $name]);
    }
}
```

and now i would like to depency inject my custom class to the invoked controller

TestController.php

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(MyCustomClass $myCustomClass)
    {

    }
}
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/depency/{filter}', TestController::class);
```

when i run this code i get an error:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string
> $name ]] in class App\Http\Custom\MyCustomClass

The question is how do I bind my class with a constructor into the service container using the helper method `app()`?

Comment: Did you [bind the class](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#simple-bindings) in a service provider? Why are you using `__invoke` in your controller? Never seen  this setup to work where the provider doesn’t know what contract or class to bind to an instance, where did you get this approach from? What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: It would be easier to explain what you want to accomplish, the way you are doing it is really strange, and doesn't make sense.

Comment: In your MyCustomClass construct method apparently you have $name required parameter. I don't see how you can inject a dependency with a required string as parameter.

Comment: inside your singleton controller  `__invoke()` method you can initialized your custom class like this `$myClass = (new MyCustomClass($name = "GregOstry"));` and than you can use it what ever you like with $myClass ...  no need to set it as static